# proving an expression involving integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, physics

Sorry If this question does not belong here, I am trying for the last six days to prove the following integration but I am failing, and I will really appreciate a lit bit of help.

I have an expression for $\tilde{M}(\beta)$:
$$
\tilde{M}(\beta)=\frac{1}{\hbar} \sum_n \left[
\left( \Omega_n  \epsilon_n^2  - m_n\epsilon_n \right)f_n(\beta) 
- \frac{m_n}{2}\epsilon_n^2 f_n'(\beta)
\right] \tag{1}
$$
here $f_n(\beta)=(e^{\beta\epsilon_n}+1)^{-1}$ and $f_n'(\beta)\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon_n}f_n(\beta)=-\beta e^{\beta\epsilon_n}(e^{\beta\epsilon_n}+1)^{-2}$.
From this equation, we want to calculate $M$ which is related to $\tilde{M}$ via relation
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}(\beta^2 M) = \beta \tilde{M} \tag{2}
$$

According to [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.8043.pdf), we get the following $M$ by integrating the above equation:
$$
M=-\frac{1}{\hbar} \sum_n \left[
 \Omega_n  \left(\int_{\epsilon_n}^\infty dz f(z) z \right)
 + \frac{m_n}{2} f_n \epsilon_n 
\right] \tag{3}
$$
here $f(z)=(e^{\beta z}+1)^{-1}$. I want to re-derive $M$ by integrating $(2)$ for my own understanding.

***My attempt:***

I start by re-writing $(2)$ as $\beta^2 M = \int_0^\beta d\beta (\beta \tilde{M}) $:

$$
\beta^2 M = \frac{1}{\hbar} \sum_n   \left[
\left( \Omega_n  \epsilon_n^2  - m_n\epsilon_n \right) \int_0^\beta d\beta (\beta f_n)
- \frac{m_n}{2}\epsilon_n^2 \int_0^\beta d\beta (\beta f_n')
\right]
$$
$$
M= \frac{1}{\beta^2\hbar} \sum_n   \left[
\left( \Omega_n  \epsilon_n^2  - m_n\epsilon_n \right) \int_0^\beta d\beta \left( \frac{\beta}{e^{\beta\epsilon_n}+1} \right)
- \frac{m_n}{2}\epsilon_n^2 \int_0^\beta d\beta  \left(\frac{-\beta^2 e^{\beta\epsilon_n}}{(e^{\beta\epsilon_n}+1)^{2} } \right)
\right]\tag{4}
$$
I arrive at these strange integrals. Can someone please help me in proving that $(4)=(3)$?

Comment: The integrals are not difficult. Is this your problem ?

Comment: First, *do not ever* use the same variable name for the variable of integration, and a variable defined outside that integration in the same context.  "$\int_0^\beta d\beta\,F(\beta)$" is surely part of why you having trouble. Since $\beta$ is defined outside the integration, you need some other variable as the dummy variable of integration: $\int_0^\beta dz\,F(z)$. This is what they did in the equation you are trying to understand. There are many, many variable names. There is no good reason to make some variables carry a double load with so many others sitting around unsued.